# Keep css animation appearing after unhovering state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div. When I hover into this div, 3 circles should pop in using css animation. But they disappear, when I move the mouse away from the div. How can I make them stay without using jquery? Here is my code:

```css
.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  list-style: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}

.circles li {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.hoverover:hover + .circles .circle {
  animation: popin .25s forwards;
}

@keyframes popin {
  80% {
    transform: scale(1.15);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverover">Hover Over Me</div>

<ul class="circles">
  <li class="circle"></li>
  <li class="circle"></li>
  <li class="circle"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to pause animation with

```
-webkit-animation-play-state: paused; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-play-state: paused;
```

And run it again on hover

```
-webkit-animation-play-state: running; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-play-state: running;
```

```html
<html>
<div class="hoverover">Hover Over Me</div>

<ul class="circles">
  <li class="circle"></li>
  <li class="circle"></li>
  <li class="circle"></li>
</ul>

<style>
.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  list-style: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}

.circles li {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.circles .circle{
   animation: popin .25s forwards;
   -webkit-animation-play-state: paused; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
.hoverover:hover + .circles .circle {
 -webkit-animation-play-state: running; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes popin {
  80% {
    transform: scale(1.15);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
</style>

</html>
```

Comment: can i make them disappear after a while? i want to keep them so the user can click on one of them if he wanted to, and after unhovering they should disappear

Answer (score 3):

To make the circles stay as long as the `.hoverover` element or they are hovered you need to insert the `.circles` container into `.hoverover`, and make some changes to the way `.circles` behave when hovered, and not hovered:

```css
.circles {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
}

.hoverover {
  display: inline-block; /** limit it to the size and height of the text **/
  height: 20px;
}

.hoverover:not(:hover) > .circles { /** prevent opening circles by hovering it when invisible **/
  pointer-events: none;
}

.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);  
}

.hoverover:hover .circle {
  animation: popin .25s forwards;
}

@keyframes popin {
  80% {
    transform: scale(1.15);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverover">
  <span>Hover Over Me</span>

  <ul class="circles">
    <li class="circle"></li>
    <li class="circle"></li>
    <li class="circle"></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

**Previous answer:**

When the `.hoverover` element is hovered, it applies the animation `animation: popin .25s forwards;` to the `.circle` elements. When the hover ends the animation is removed, and the element disappears.

To solve that start the animation paused on the `.circle`, and "resume" it when `.hoverover` is hovered:

```css
.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  list-style: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  animation: popin .25s forwards;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.circles li {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.hoverover:hover + .circles .circle {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes popin {
  80% {
    transform: scale(1.15);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverover">Hover Over Me</div>

<ul class="circles">
  <li class="circle"></li>
  <li class="circle"></li>
  <li class="circle"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You're a true GENIUS!

Comment: can i make them disappear after a while? i want to keep them so the user can click on one of them if he wanted to, and after unhovering they should disappear

Comment: Nothing changed they're still there when i unhover

Comment: @OriDrori it doesn't work on the other code i dont know why :/

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: google chrome, when i apply this code on it, the buttons stop appearing

Comment: on this question yes but the other one i asked no

Comment: It's the same principle. Try to understand how it works, and implement it on your current code.